# plotting on PyQt6

Tags: python, qt, graph, pyqt6

I already wrote here before, but I deleted the question, because there were no specifics. Now I'll bring it in.
I have an application that I have developed in PyQt6. It contains three buttons for switching: if you click on the " 2 page"  button, there will be 2 pages with the inscription 2 page and similarly with the "3 page" button. The question is: page 1 should display a plot, in the pizdec area, however I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'plot'.`

I'm not really good at OOP yet, so I don't quite understand how to fix it. For plotting i use pyqtgraph library.
Code generated by Qt Designer.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1495, 788)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 761))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.frame)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 111, 261))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 1371, 31))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 30, 1371, 731))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);\n"
"background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.graph = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(parent=self.frame_3)
        self.graph.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1361, 721))
        self.graph.setObjectName("graph")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.pizdec = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.page)
        self.pizdec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 1231, 441))
        self.pizdec.setObjectName("pizdec")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 100, 831, 401))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 831, 401))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1495, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuw3rrewd = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menuw3rrewd.setObjectName("menuw3rrewd")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuw3rrewd.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 page"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 page"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 page"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 page"))
        self.menuw3rrewd.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "w3rrewd"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here's the logic code I wrote.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from untdwdfd import Ui_MainWindow
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
       
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

        self.pizdec.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_3_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_2_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYA6B.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCAHa.jpg)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2hFq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your `UI` file you might notice that `self.pizdec` is defined as a `QWidget`.

```
#line 80ish
self.pizdec = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.page)
self.pizdec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 1231, 441))
self.pizdec.setObjectName("pizdec")
```

And then in your logic file you are calling:

```
self.pizdec.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

You are receiving the error because `QWidget` doesn't have a `plot` method.

You technically shouldn't edit the uic files, so what you can do is edit your ui in designer and leave an empty space where `self.pizdec` is and then add the widget in your logic file.

For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from untdwdfd import Ui_MainWindow
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
       
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.pizdec = QPlotWidget(parent=self.page)
        self.pizdec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 1231, 441))
        self.pizdec.setObjectName("pizdec")
        self.pizdec.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_3_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_2_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are choices: either just leave an empty "space" in the layout and add the plot widget by code, or use promoted widgets. Even in this case, editing the pyuic file is **not** a valid option.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I would never have thought that the graph should be inserted into an empty space.